# Combine two "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)"

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following two codes in my sheet, and I want them both to run - currently I get a macro error. Could you help me to combine them so that they both run??

One enters the date in an adjacent cell when data is entered, the other allows multiple selections from a dropdown list. Both work individually.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("O:O"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 1
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

And the other code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column = 10 _
     Or Target.Column = 12 Then
    If oldVal = "" Then
       'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      Target.Value = oldVal _
    & ", " & newVal
'      NOTE: you can use a line break,
'      instead of a comma
'      Target.Value = oldVal _
'        & Chr(10) & newVal
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: *"currently I get a macro error. "* - what is the error and on what line?

Comment: If you have put `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` twice in the same worksheet, it won't work. Rename them to e.g. `Private Sub Worksheet_Change1(ByVal Target As Range)` and `Private Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)` and make the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` simply call them both.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one `Worksheet_Change` event per sheet. A simple work around is to turn your two `Events` into `Sub Procedures` and then create a master `Event` that simply calls both of your other subs.

The set up will look something like this

---

### Event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    AddDate Target
    Dropdown Target
End Sub
```

### Sub Procedure 1

```
Sub AddDate (Target as Range)
    'Your first code goes here
End Sub
```

### Sub Procedure 2

```
Sub Dropdown (Target as Range)
    'Your second code goes here
End Sub
```

---

I would personally set up your validations in the `Event` and call your procedures accordingly. Then your subs can strictly focus on the action statements rather needing to do any validation.

That may look something like this (notice all of your range variables are already initiated and no longer need to be declared)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'DateAdd Validation
Dim WorkRng As Range
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("O:O"), Target)

If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    DateAdd Target, WorkRng
End If

'Dropdown Validation
Dim rngDV As Range
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)

If Target.Count = 1 Then
    If Not rngDV Is Nothing Then '<-- I believe this is redundant
        If Not Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
            Dropdown Target, rngDV
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

```
Sub DateAdd(Target As Range, WorkRng As Range)

End Sub
```

```
Sub Dropdown(Target As Range, rngDV As Range)

End Sub
```