# How to write code to click & select multiple values and input one cell with comma separation

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code in excel that allows me to click & select multiple values and input into one cell with comma separation.

Attached is a screenshot of how i wish to achieve the final result in the yellow boxes to select by clicking multiple values and input them into a cell in the Excel sheet.

[image]

I try to draft the code below into Sheet1 but it is not working:-

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Row < 10 Or Target.Row > 101 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Me.Range("C:C,E:E, G:G"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  
    Me.Cells(7, Target.Column).Value = Target.Value
    Active.Cell= Range("E10")& Range("E11")& Range("E12")& Range("E13") & Range ("E14") & Range ("E15") & Range("E16')& (Range"E17")  
End Sub
```

I try but could not get the multiple choices to fit into one cell; and i also could not get a comma separation in the multi-choices yellow box. 
I would appreciate it if you could help to correct my mistake.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you wanna click (and thus select) each cell and it should add that cell? The first line in your code checks if multiple cells are selected, and disregards the selection if so. So I assume a simple click on the cell should add it? I don't quite understand the logic of the last row. After someone selected something, you want the macro to select range E10-17?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Row < 10 Or Target.Row > 101 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Me.Range("C:C,E:E, G:G"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub


    If Me.Cells(7, Target.Column).Value = "" Then
        Me.Cells(7, Target.Column).Value = Target.Value
    Else
        Me.Cells(7, Target.Column).Value = Me.Cells(7, Target.Column).Value & ", " & Target.Value
    End If

    'Really?
    'Range("E10:E17").Select

End Sub
```

I added an if statement to add the first entry after the yellow box has been cleared. Seems to work for me.

Comment: To: Czeskleba_Thank you very much for your reply. The code you have crafted works very well. Based the code, all 3 columns (at C, E and G) will generate multiple values with comma at row 7. 
But what if i wish to generate multiple values with comma for Column E at Cell E7, and single value only at cell C7 and G7 based on my screenshot of my previous post? I await your advice. Thank you.

Comment: To: Czeskleba_ It is OK, I have found the answer to my second query on the above in stackoverflow by urdearboy of 2019-02-07 in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563319/combine-two-private-sub-worksheet-changebyval-target-as-range].  His answer is to turn the 2 events into sub procedures and then create a master event that calls both of the subs. So i combine both urdearboy's and your code. It works! Thank you once again. From Tan LC 2020-02-10